# Differential equation $y'''− 2y = x^2 − 3x + 2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I spent most of the day trying to solve this problem but I couldn't do it. I have tried an exponential function for homogeneous part and the equal roots method. Any solution, even partial, would help me a lot, thank you!

Comment: Please show us your work trying an exponential function for the homogeneous part and the equal roots method.  Maybe we can help figure out where you went wrong.  But please don't ask us to solve the DE for you.

Comment: What is the characteristic equation?  What are its roots?  What does a real root imply?  What does a complex root imply?

Comment: I will try to give more details next time, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's find the solution to the associated homogeneous differential equation $y'''-a^3y=0$ where $a=\sqrt[3]{2}$. The characteristic equation is $$\lambda^3-a^3=(\lambda-a)(\lambda^2+a\lambda+a^2)=0$$ The solutions to the previous equation are $$\lambda=a,-\frac{a}{2} \pm \frac{ia\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ This means $$y_h(x)=c_1e^{ax}+c_2e^{-ax/2}\cos\Big(\frac{ax\sqrt{3}}{2}\Big)+c_3e^{-ax/2}\sin\Big(\frac{ax\sqrt{3}}{2}\Big)$$ We can find a particular solution $y_p$ via variation of parameters, but it's much easier using the method of undetermined coefficients. Assume $y_p$ takes the form $$y_p(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$$ where $A,B,C$ are constants to be determined. Notice $$y_p'''(x)=0$$ Plugging into the original equation yields $$(-2A)x^2+(-2B)x+(-2C)=x^2-3x+2$$ This means $A=-\frac{1}{2},B=\frac{3}{2},$ and $C=-1$. The general solution becomes $$y(x)=c_1e^{ax}+c_2e^{-ax/2}\cos\Big(\frac{ax\sqrt{3}}{2}\Big)+c_3e^{-ax/2}\sin\Big(\frac{ax\sqrt{3}}{2}\Big)-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3x}{2}-1$$ Remember, $a=\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time

Comment: no problem. just make sure you do lots of other problems like this one to get adequate practice :)